# Using null Model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have two classes:
Gallery with some attributes
Location with some attributes and one gallery.
I would like to have or not a gallery in location, so I did like this:

```
public Gallery? Gallery { get; set; }
```

The problem is that I'm getting this error:

```
Error   3   The type 'Gallery' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'
```

I've been looking for this error, but I could't find any solution (at least that I understood). My question is how can I fix this situation?

Comment: Let me guess: `Gallery` is a class?

Comment: Gallery is (presumably) a class, which is naturally nullable and can't be used with `?`, which is a decoration for a struct. If `Gallery` is optional on your `Location` model, indicate that with a nullable *id* property as the foreign key. For example, `public int? GalleryId { get; set; }`

Comment: Why do you use "Gallery?" while Gallery is a class, thus nullable type?

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: you could just define `Gallery` as optional in the ORM layer, no? That way you can keep the navigational property.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel, the Id property is in addition to the navigation property. You would define both.

Comment: @AnthonyPegram: not necessarily, though? At least I don't believe EF needs  both -- you can use either an ID or a navigation property on their own.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> public Gallery? Gallery { get; set; }

This means:

1. `Gallery` is a type that cannot be null.
2. The `Gallery` property can either be a `Gallery` or `null`.

The first of these isn't true. Therefore either:

1. Change `Gallery` so that it can't be null by changing `class Gallery` to `struct Gallery`.
2. Change the property to `public Gallery Gallery { get; set; }` to use the fact that `Gallery` as currently defined can already be null.